# Javascript not running Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop, countdown, countdowntimer

Im trying to add a countdowns shipping time, using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/37ox54bk/7/

I use the HTML box module: https://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/html-box.html

The code looks like this:

```
    <div id="countdownTimer">0</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     if (document.getElementById('countdownTimer')) {
pad = function(n, len) { // leading 0's
    var s = n.toString();
    return (new Array( (len - s.length + 1) ).join('0')) + s;
};

var timerRunning = setInterval(

    function countDown() {
        var target = 15; // 15:00hrs is the cut-off point
        var now = new Date();

        //Put this in a variable for convenience
        var weekday = now.getDay();

        if(weekday == 0){//Sunday? Add 24hrs
            target += 24;
        }//keep this before the sunday, trust me :>

        if(weekday == 6){//It's Saturday? Add 48hrs
            target += 48;
        }

        //If between Monday and Friday, 
        //check if we're past the target hours, 
        //and if we are, abort.
        if((weekday>=1) && (weekday<=5)){
            if (now.getHours() > target) { //stop the clock
                return 0;
            }                
        }

        var hrs = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
        if (hrs < 0) hrs = 0;
        var mins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
        if (mins < 0) mins = 0;
        var secs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
        if (secs < 0) secs = 0;

        var str = pad(hrs, 2) + ':' + pad(mins, 2) + '.<small>' + pad(secs, 2) + '</small>';
        document.getElementById('countdownTimer').innerHTML = str;

    }, 1000
);
    }// ]]></script>
```

But nothing is happening, it just shows 0 like the javascript is not running.
Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Did you check if you have any error in your browser console? Also check in the source code of your page that the javascript is well included after your `<div id="countdownTimer">0</div>` dom element.

Comment: I got this error in console: SyntaxError: missing } after function body. I can see the javascript in the code.

Comment: Ok so you've got another javascript breaking your code. You'll have to search for this particular javascript throwing this error.

Comment: Seems the code i added makes that error. Can you see any fault in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that module wraps everything inside `<script>` tags in

```
// <![CDATA[
//--><![CDATA[//><!-- //
[your code] 
//--><!
// ]]>
```

It doesn't look like that's even the correct way to use CDATA but in any case i think all this achieves in your case is commenting the whole piece of code out.

Do you not have access to the files in your theme? You could for instance still add the `<div id="countdownTimer">0</div>` with the module and paste your code into the `document.ready();` function of the globals.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a js file and link it like this:

```
<script src="http://yoursite.com/folder/file.js"></script>
<div id="countdownTimer">0</div>
```

And if you need to add some css code you have to add it on your current css prestashop file (for example if you need to add it on your homepage so you've to work on golbal.css)

Hope it can help you